# get multiple data using jquery and split

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to get `query1` and `query2` from a `span` tag and im using `split(_)`. for example query i want to get.

`<span id='post1_query1_query2'>`

and here my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( " span" ).tooltip({
        track:true,
        open: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.tooltip.css("max-width", "600px");
              var id = this.id;
              var split_id = id.split('_');
              var image = split_id[1];
              var title = split_id[2];
              $.ajax({
                  url:'fetch_details.php',
                  type:'post',
                  data:{image:image},
                  data:{title:title},
                  success: function(response){
                      $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);
                  }
              });
        }
    });
    $(" span").mouseout(function(){
        // re-initializing tooltip
        $(this).tooltip();
        $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
    });
});
```

and then i call it to fetch_details.php

```
$post = htmlentities ($_POST['image']);
$title = htmlentities ($_POST['title']);
```

but not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: "not working" is not enough detail to solve the problem. do you get errors? What do you expect and what happens instead? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass multiple key-pair in data object.

```
             $.ajax({
                  url:'fetch_details.php',
                  type:'post',
                  data:{image: image, title: title},
                  success: function(response){
                      $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);
                  }
              });
```

Comment: yes, the right one is value and left one is key. 
you can also write this like. `data:{"image": image, "title": title}`